# Java exec Error: Fatal system Error 1020005

Tags: java, exec, fatal-error

I have a problem with a Java program. I uses a tool "ugpc" to get the assembly structure and write it in a textfile. When i start the program under netbeans it writes these files without problem. but when i compile it to a jar file and run this jar, i get the error "Error: Fatal system Error 1020005" written in the proc.getErrorStream(); and no .txt file ist written in the ouput. Also in the ErrorStream appears that the textfile can not be found, but he should write it and not open it. My PC is new installed and before that formatting the tool was running good. I use Java 7. When I manually start the command via cmd it works also fine. We startet the tool under another user account and the same error appears.

```
 Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c " + "c:\\ugs\\nx6\\UGII\\ugpc -a -s2 " +"S:\\Geraete\\L\\0154\\E2\\6169-001000-201_Rev-E2_DWG.prt" + " > " + "S:\\LAUF5\\1\\6169-001000-201_Rev-E2_DWG.txt");

 proc.waitFor();
```

Comment: Edit question including the error that you receive.
And also was it running good whlie using java7 earlier?

Comment: The code is not a valid Java fragment.  Please update the question so that we know what code you are actually trying to run.

Comment: I receive no runtime error in java. There are only errors in the ErrorStream. I updatet the fragment, and this is the main part of the program. do you need more information?